# What is the least natural number not known to be the difference between a cube and a square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We have $0=0^2-0^3,\;$ $1=1^2-0^3,\;$ and $2=3^3-5^2$, and (just as easily) $4=2^2-0^3$; but already I'm wondering how far one has to search to find an integral solution $(l,m)$ to $$|l^3-m^2|=n$$when  $n=3$, or indeed whether such a solution exists. My question then is: Within the natural numbers, what is the smallest ($3$ perhaps?) not known to be the difference between a cube and a square?

As a supplementary question: Is it known whether there is any integer that cannot be formed as such a difference and, if so, has any such integer been identified?

Comment: $3=2^2-1^3$. It seems that the answer is $6$ according to [A081121](http://oeis.org/A081121) and [A054504](http://oeis.org/A054504).

Comment: @mathlove Following on from your reference, I found Mordell's curve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve

Comment: @mathlove: Doh! How could I have missed that?

Comment: Thank you @ColmBhandal. Just the name Mordell is the key that was needed.